# How to manage multiple IAM users on a single EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

For different AWS services, I need different IAM users to secure the access control. Sometimes, I even need to use different IAM user credentials within a single project in a EC2 instance. What's the proper way to manage this and how I can deploy/attach these IAM user credentials to a single EC2 instance?

Comment: Did you already thought of using ECS (Elastic Container Service)? Under the hood you have `1-n` EC2-Instance(s) but you are able to deploy multiple containers (Tasks) and for each Task you are able to attach different IAM Role (with different permissions).

Comment: Haven't thought about that. But let's assume I have a monolithic project with multiple java classes using different AWS services with different IAM users. Is there a way to cope with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to provide credentials to applications running on an Amazon EC2 instance is to assign an IAM Role to the instance. Temporary credentials associated with the role when then be provided via Instance Metadata. The AWS SDKs will automatically use these credentials.

However, this only works for one set of credentials. If you wish to use **more than one credential**, you will need to provide the credentials in a **credentials file**.

The AWS credentials file can contain multiple profiles, eg:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKIAaaaaa
aws_secret_access_key = abcdefg

[user2]
aws_access_key_id = AKIAbbbb
aws_secret_access_key = xyzzzy
```

As a convenience, this can also be configured via the AWS CLI:

```
$ aws configure --profile user2
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAbbbb
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: xyzzy
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]: text
```

The profile to use can be set via an Environment Variable:

- Linux: `export AWS_PROFILE="user2"`
- Windows: `set AWS_PROFILE="user2"`

Alternatively, when calling AWS services via an SDK, simply specify the Profile to use. Here is an example with Python from [Credentials — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html):

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='user2')
# Any clients created from this session will use credentials
# from the [user2] section of ~/.aws/credentials.
dev_s3_client = session.client('s3')
```

There is an equivalent capability in the SDKs for other languages, too.

Comment: Thanks, John. The problem is: how can we easily deploy these IAM credentials to the EC2 instances? Usually, one project might use multiple EC2 instances.

Comment: Well, you could deploy one set of credentials via the IAM Role. Using that role, the application could then retrieve other credentials from the AWS Secrets Manager or the Systems manager Parameter Store.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then, I guess we can achieve the goal by using the AWS Secrets Manager only. Thanks, John!

Comment: Well, you'd need to still use an initial set of credentials to access AWS Secrets Manager.

Comment: That's true. For the rest of the work, I'll use AWS Secrets Manager :-)

Answer (score 2):

While I fully agree with accepted answer that using static credentials is  one way of solving this problem, I would like to suggest some improvements over it (and proposed Secrets Manager).

What I would advise as architectural step forward to achieve full isolation of credentials, having them dynamic, and not stored in central place (Secrets Manager proposed above) is dockerizing application and running on AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS). This way you can assign different IAM role to different ECS Tasks.

Benefits over Secrets Manager solution
- use case of someone tampering with credentials in Secrets Manager is fully avoided, as credentials are of dynamic nature (temporary, and automatically assumed through SDKs)

- Credentials are managed on AWS side for you
- Only ECS Service can assume this IAM role, meaning you can't have actual person stealing the credentials, or developer connecting to production environment from his local machine with this credentials.

[AWS Official Documentation for Task Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html)